# Postgres function to convert a pair of 64-bit numbers into a string representing the 128 bit number

Tags: postgresql

I have a data type in Postgres that represents via a pair of 64-bit numbers, a 128 bit number.

I would like to write a PostgreSQL function that reads the pair of 64-bit numbers and converts into a string that represents the equivalent of the 128-bit number.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A 64bit integer is 8bytes or 16hex digits. You can use the to_hex function to convert the value and lpad function to generate the necessary leading 0, for a given number, concatenate them to give a 32hex digits. (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c2ce50adeba319cad10d6029264872a))

```
select concat ( lpad( (to_hex(coalesce(num1,0))::text),16,'0') 
              , lpad( (to_hex(coalesce(num2,0))::text),16,'0')
              ) 
  from <table> ;
```